# Remove view controller from another view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to iPhone app development.
I am developing one example application for iPhone emulator using Objective-C++ and std CPP.

I have two views in my application, on some events from CPP code i am displaying second view using following code from the first view controller.

```
// Defined in .h file 
secondViewScreenController *mSecondViewScreen;

// .mm file Code gets called based on event from CPP (common interface function between Objective-C++ and CPP code)
mSecondViewScreen = [[secondViewScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:mSecondViewScreen animated:YES];
```

I am able to see second view coming on screen, but problem is that i am unable to end/remove second view controller from first view controller.

How can i remove second view controller from first view controller using second view controller's pointer or using any other method.

To remove second view i have following code in second view controller file, which gets called on button click event of second view.

```
// In .mm of second view controller. 
- (IBAction)onEndBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Above code works perfectly, when i click on the seconds view's end button it removes the second view controller from the screen and navigets to first view, how can i use same code to remove second view from the first view controller.

I tied to use `NSNotificationCenter` to send event from first view to second view to call the function `onEndBtnClicked` but it is not working.

What is the proper way of doing it?

OSX version: 10.5.8 and Xcode version: 3.1.3

Comment: Show also the part when you use NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the secondViewController create a protocol like:

```
@protocol SecondViewScreenControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)secondViewScreenControllerDidPressCancelButton:(UIViewController *)viewController sender:(id)sender;

// Any other button possibilities

@end
```

Now you have to add a property in the secondViewController class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondViewScreenControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

You sinthesize it in the secondViewController implementation:

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

Finally all you have to do is implement the protocol in your firstViewController and set the secondViewController properly prior presenting it:

```
@interface firstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewScreenControllerDelegate>
```

...

```
@implementation firstViewController

    - (void)secondViewScreenControllerDidPressCancelButton:(UIViewController *)viewController sender:(id)sender
    {
         // Do something with the sender if needed
         [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

Then when presenting the secondViewController from the first:

```
UIViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; // If you don't need any nib don't call the method, use init instead
sec.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And ready. Whenever you want to dismiss the secondViewController from the first, just call: (inside the secondViewController implementation)

```
[self.delegate secondViewScreenControllerDidPressCancelButton:self sender:nil]; // Use nil or any other object to send as a sender
```

All that happens is that you send a pointer of the secondViewController that you can use from the first. Then you can work with it without problem. No C++ needed. In Cocoa you won't need C++. Almost everything can be done with Objective-C, and it's more dynamic.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will try your suggestion and let you know the results. I am using CPP with Objective-C as i have native (CPP) code which has all the basic functionality for my application and i want to reuse it.

Comment: i am getting compilation errors after adding your code,  I am getting errors after adding "@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondViewScreenControllerDelegate> delegate;" to secondViewController.h file. Can you please suggest one complete example for this, as i don't know where to exactly add above code lines. I think i might be doing some mistakes.

Comment: I thought it's easier to use these two UIViewController properties: presentingViewController and presentedViewController. When you are editing the secondViewController implementation: use self. presentingViewController or [self presentingViewController] to get the first one. But if you only need to dismiss the view controller you can do it with the second one: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]. If you have more problems post the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two views in your application then use

```
- (IBAction)onEndBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

remove line below:

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

as it is you are dismissing second view then why you want to remove it from first view.

Comment: "why you want to remove it from first view.", on some events from the CPP code i want to remove second view, those events are received in first view controller and because of that i need to remove second view from first view controller.