# dismissViewControllerAnimated crash in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a application that work very well in iOS7.0/7.1
Since the last iOS update (8.0) the dismissViewControllerAnimated crash every time. Someone saw the same thing ?
I have a control this to call the second controller:

```
**detailViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];**
```

and in the close button I use this:

```
**// Do something with the sender if needed
[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];**
```

I Used this ([Remove view controller from another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021309/remove-view-controller-from-another-view-controller)) as a guide for implementation the "second" control but the crash appear again.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How about the idea that if you ask a question about a "crash" you include the complete, exact exception message plus the exception stack trace?

Comment: Since this user is apparently very new to SO, we should ask him if the error he got said "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: I've got the same thing going on in the ShareKit library with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Not to hijack the thread, but I've verified the presented ViewController and the presenting ViewController both are still alive at a breakpoint just before the crash. Also verified it is iOS 8 only.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue when I was dismissing programmatically.  (like when a delegate finished a process).

I used this and it worked perfectly:

```
if (![self isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

It simply checks to see if it was already in the process of being dismissed.  Hope this works for you!

Comment: @Andrew You can add this code wherever you want to dismiss the view controller.  You don't need to override anything.  In my case, it was an IBAction method of a "Cancel" button.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any dealloc function defined as mentioned below. As it might led to Crash Sometimes.

```
- (void)dealloc {
      [_yourview release]; //don't do this
      [super dealloc];
}
```